# Dynamically created dropdown using xml data is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

My requirement is to create bootstrap dropdown from the xml data received from the backed i done that but i cant able to select any particular element in the list please help me to fix this.

Html content

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
<span id="demo"></span>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS content

```
var abc = "<getexternalworkloads>Cinebench,3DMark11,Furmark,Others<getexternalworkloads>"
if (abc != "") {
abc = abc.replace(new RegExp("<getexternalworkloads>", "g"), "");
abc = abc.split(",");
array  = [];
array = array.concat(abc);

var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    text += array[i] + "<br>";
    afg = '<li  ><a href="#">'+text+'</a></li>'
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = afg;
```

The out put i a[image]

Comment: Why do you have a `<span>` inside your `<ul>`?

Comment: my requirement is to dynamically create dropdown elements from xml data received from backed.So here i created li inside for loop and showing inside span.What else i can do here

Comment: But then there is no `#demo` element. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: #demo i mentioned inside span tag.<span id="demo"></span>

Comment: Kindly suggest a better way to develop dropdown dynamically  using xml data received from backend.

Comment: Then my first comment applies again. Have you considered giving the `<ul>` the ID `demo`? A `<span>` inside a `<ul>` is invalid.

Comment: ok accepted,Can you please tel the valid scenario for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your existing code was full of errors. But instead of correcting all, lets start by using **JQuery**. Since you are using **Bootstrap** there is no harm in that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var abc = "<getexternalworkloads>Cinebench,3DMark11,Furmark,Others<getexternalworkloads>"
if (abc != "") {
 abc = abc.replace("<getexternalworkloads>", "").split(",")
  .forEach( function(el, index) {
   $("#demo").append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'+el+'</a>');
 });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul id="demo" class="dropdown-menu"> 
   </ul>
  </div>
```

> PS: In Bootstrap, classes are important, meaning you don't
>   neceserallly have to use `<ul` or `<li>` tags to get what you need.
>
> Also, in your code it seems that you are overusing variables. Try to
>   avoid that.

Comment: Thank fr your answer

Comment: If you accept the answer, it would be a nice gesture and can help others as well.